Find the Gauss curvature for the Poincare metric $g'=\frac{16(dx^2+dy^2)}{(4-x^2-y^2)^2}$
Find the Gauss curvature for the Poincare metric $$g'=\frac{16(dx^2+dy^2)}{(4-x^2-y^2)^2}$$ i.e. $$K'=\frac{R'(\partial_i,\partial_j,\partial_j,\partial_i)}{g'(\partial_i,\partial_i)g'(\partial_j,\partial_j)-g'(\partial_i,\partial_j)^2}$$
Attempt
Suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold and define the metric $g'=e^{2\omega}g$, where $\omega\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$. Reading Sakai's book, I find that $$R'=e^{2\omega}\left\{R+\left(Hess(\omega)-d\omega \otimes d\omega+\frac{1}{2}g(\nabla {\omega},\nabla {\omega})g\right)\newcommand\KN{\bigcirc
\kern-2.5ex\wedge \;}\KN g\right\}\;(\star)$$ where $\renewcommand\vec[1]{{\boldsymbol #1}}$if $V$ is a vector space and $T,S \in \mathfrak{T}^0_{\;\;2}(V)$ are covariant tensors of type $(0,2)$, then we define their Kulkarni-Nomizu$\newcommand\KN{\bigcirc
\kern-2.5ex\wedge \;}$ product $T \KN S \in \mathfrak{T}^0_{\;\;4}(V)$ by $$(T \KN S)(\vec{x},\vec{y},\vec{z},\vec{w}) \doteq T(\vec{x},\vec{z})S(\vec{y},\vec{w}) + T(\vec{y},\vec{w})S(\vec{x},\vec{z})-T(\vec{x},\vec{w})S(\vec{y},\vec{z}) - T(\vec{y},\vec{z})S(\vec{x},\vec{w}).$$
I have tried in $(\star)$ to get
$$R'(x,y,y,x)=e^{2\omega}\left\{R(x,y,y,x)+\left(\left[Hess(\omega)-d\omega \otimes d\omega+\frac{1}{2}g(\nabla {\omega},\nabla {\omega})g\right]\newcommand\KN{\bigcirc
\kern-2.5ex\wedge \;}\KN g\right)(x,y,y,x)\right\}$$

It seems that $K'$ should depend on $Hess(\omega)$ but not on $\Delta \omega$. Is your formula for $K'$ actually correct?

I think it works only in dimension 2.but how to prove it?

@ArcticChar I have edited my question with the original source. Do you have any ideas, please?

Note that you know what $g$ is and therefore also $R(x,y,y,x)$. Since you know the formula for $\omega$, you can also calculate the Hessian of $\omega$, $d\omega$, $\nabla\omega$ with respect to the coordinates $x, y$. Please also note that you are using the letters $x, y$ to denote both coordinates and vector fields. This is not a good idea.

The "usual" formula for the Gaussian curvature $K$ for a metric $f^2(x,y)(dx^2+dy^2)$ would be $K=-\Delta_{LB}(\ln f)$ where $\Delta_{LB}$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\frac{1}{f^2}\Delta_0$.  I am not aware of any particularly elegant way of proving this other than calculation, which is not hard; see for example my lecture notes.
